# LUA: Generating Unique Mac from given Number Value

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I am trying to generate a unique MAC id from given a number value. The length on the number is between 1 to 5 digit. I have formatted the MAC table to place each digit starting from first value of MAC.

```
local MacFormat ={[1] = "0A:BC:DE:FA:BC:DE",[2] = "00:BC:DE:FA:BC:DE",[3] = "00:0C:DE:FA:BC:DE",[4] = "00:00:DE:FA:BC:DE",[5] = "00:00:0E:FA:BC:DE"}

local idNumbers = {[1] = "1",[2]="12",[3]="123",[4]="1234",[5]="12345"}

for w in string.gfind(idNumbers[3], "(%d)") do
      print(w)
str = string.gsub(MacFormat[3],"0",tonumber(w))
    end
print(str)
---output 33:3C:DE:FA:BC:DE
--- Desired Output 12:3C:DE:FA:BC:DE
```

I have tried multiple Patterns with `*`, `+`, `.`, but none is working.

Comment: it works perfectly in my compiler

Comment: what version of lua are you using?

Comment: it's 5.3 only. Here is the screenshot

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19rlLnGauBLnPCpO18BNosZs065ITbTNV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew string.gfind was renamed into string.gmatch in Lua 5.1, from Lua 5.1 string.gfind is nil unless compiled with compatibility option LUA_COMPAT_GFIND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the pattern and replacement dynamically:

```lua
local MacFormat ={[1] = "0A:BC:DE:FA:BC:DE",[2] = "00:BC:DE:FA:BC:DE",[3] = "00:0C:DE:FA:BC:DE",[4] = "00:00:DE:FA:BC:DE",[5] = "00:00:0E:FA:BC:DE"}
local idNumbers = {[1] = "1",[2]="12",[3]="123",[4]="1234",[5]="12345"}

local p = "^" .. ("0"):rep(string.len(idNumbers[3])):gsub("(..)", "%1:")
local repl = idNumbers[3]:gsub("(..)", "%1:")
local str = MacFormat[3]:gsub(p, repl)

print(str)
-- => 12:3C:DE:FA:BC:DE
```

See the [online Lua demo](https://ideone.com/Oe5lhF).

The pattern is `"^" .. ("0"):rep(string.len(idNumbers[3])):gsub("(..)", "%1:")`: `^` matches the start of string, then a string of zeros (of the same size a `idNumbers`, see `("0"):rep(string.len(idNumbers[3]))`) follows with a `:` after each pair of zeros (`:gsub("(..)", "%1:")`).

The replacement is the `idNumbers` item with a colon inserted after every second char with `idNumbers[3]:gsub("(..)", "%1:")`.

In this current case, the pattern will be `^00:0` and the replacement will be `12:3`.

See the [full demo](https://ideone.com/iTWiP2) here.

Answer (score 2):

```
for w in string.gfind(idNumbers[3], "(%d)") do
      print(w)
str = string.gsub(MacFormat[3],"0",tonumber(w))
    end
print(str)
```

Your loop body is equivalent to

```
str = string.gsub("00:0C:DE:FA:BC:DE", "0",1)
str = string.gsub("00:0C:DE:FA:BC:DE", "0", 2)
str = string.gsub("00:0C:DE:FA:BC:DE", "0", 3)
```

So `str` is `"33:3C:DE:FA:BC:DE"`

`MacFormat[3]` is never altered and the result of `gsub` is overwritten in each line.